# multiple makefiles same variable names

Tags: makefile

im trying to write a non recursive make build system.
what im trying to accomplish is that each makefile will define its own variables and "feel" like he is the only one in the system.
for example:
Project layout:
-Makefile
-src1
----Makefile
----example1.c
-src2
----Makfile
----example2.c

the main Makefile looks like this:
include src1/Makefile
include src2/Makefile
all: $(TARGETS)

each of src1/src2 makefile looks like this:
SRC:=...
OBJ:=...
TARGETS+=bin1 #in src2 its bin2
bin1: $(OBJ)
----gcc ....
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
----gcc ....

but this design pattern does not work as the evaluation of recipe in the targets is deferred.
this means all the variables with the same name in src1 gets the value of src2 variables(the last assignment). i tried to replace the include with $(eval include ...) but no luck.
please note that all the variables assignment is done with :=
is there a way to accomplish that each makefile can define what he wants or each variable should be unique?

thanks,
tal

Comment: Where should the object files go? I mean, is there `obj1/`? or maybe `src1/obj/`? Or just 'obj/'?

Comment: Come to think of it, where should the executables go? If you run Make in `src1`, it should build `src1/bin1`. But if you run Make in the main directory, should it build `bin1` and `bin2`, or `src1/bin1` and `src2/bin2`?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to do that. When I've done this in one or two places I've started with make snippets in each directory that can be included from the master make file, and ended up with a scripted approach which scans the make snippets and generates something else. And I had a VPATH in there as well.

There's an example of how this might be achieved in the 'recursive make considered harmful' paper which might be of help.